What exactly causes the measurable voltage shown in an ECG/EKG?
I am familiar with how an ECG works (measuring current to determine voltage), with heart physiology, and also the mechanism of muscle action potentials. A lot of sources describe the action potential as perpendicular transmembrane flow of ions in and out of the cell. However, what confuses me is that an ECG is able to record the "flow" of the action potential across the heart muscle. Wouldn't this mean that there is some ion flow in the direction of the AP? And not just perpendicular ion flow in and out of the cells during de/repolarisation?
What I assume happens is that what is actually being measured is the small flow of ions leaking across the gap junctions between myocardial cells.
Can someone clarify how ECGs work and what it is actually measuring? Much thanks.

Took electrocardiography 30 years ago,  As I recall, the value on an EKG at any time and across any lead is the voltage difference between the two points (different leads).  There is no general movement of ions across the heart from one lead to another.  The The contraction of muscle cells near one lead do contribute to depolarizing adjacent cells though.  It does raise a couple physics question though.  I'll review and see if I can formulate an answer.

What you're referring to here is recognized by your ECG as mean operating values a commonly accepted as a one constant of the Conduction Systems that exist in the heart and brain. Through the sodium ion channels of the tissues of the involved organ. Operating correctly ekg,ecg values are tuned for the recording and reception of that minuscule amount of electrical current flow. More or less is recognized as a functioning deficit in your patient. Electrolytic deficit categorized needing an influx of Electrolytes depending on patient injuries and imposing symptoms determines level of infusion.
ie; synaptic tissues,over axons to dendritic tissues. I'm going to query it,through a friend a Cardiopulmonologyst. Get back afterwards.

This is completely incomprehensible. I do not think you understand the question asked.

Actual people don't speak or write like this; even folks with flight of ideas make more sense than this does. Hopefully it's an AI generated answer. A bad AI generated answer to boot. (Use a different site.) -1. (Although reading it made me chuckle, so there's that.) ["Electrolytic deficit categorized needing an influx of Electrolytes depending on patient injuries and imposing symptoms determines level of infusion. ie; synaptic tissues,over axons to dendritic tissues." lol!]

I'll give this the benefit of the doubt and say that it's an absolutely  awful translation of a potentially good basis for an answer. Please [edit] to prove me correct, hopefully adding supporting references as you go.
